# Android load Images into a GridView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I want to load local pictures into a GridView.

my code in my adapter is

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));


        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }


    Bitmap btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images.get(position).getAbsolutePath());

    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(btmp);
    btmp = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(btmp, 128,128);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(btmp);
    return imageView;
}
```

now my Problem is that it takes quite long (few seconds) to load my app. And scrolling is also very balking.

Is there a fast way to create thumbnails for the overview of my pictures?

Or is there a way that the grid cells are loaded parallel?
Or display just a blank picture and replace that after the thumbnail is loaded?

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Picasso Library   **http://square.github.io/picasso/**

Picasso.with(context)
    .load(R.drawable.your_image)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_waitong)
 
    .error(R.drawable.icon_error)
    .into(imageView);